# Finding Possible Words in an Ever Changing Grid

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a word game where the user creates words from an ever changing grid of letters. Validating the users selection is easy enough to do using a wordlist.

Since the playing grid is randomly generated and previously played tiles are removed and replaced with new letters, I need to be able to effectively check for possible valid plays between each user submission, so if there are no possible valid words I can reset the grid or something to that affect. The solution only needs to detect that there is at least one valid 3 - 7 letter word within the current set of tiles. It does not need to know ever possible combination. A user can start on any tile and build a word using one tile away in any direction from the currently selected letter.

**Important:** The solution can't slow the game play down. As soon as the user submits the current word and the new tiles appear they can start a new selection without delay.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated as I have not been able to find what I think I'm looking for with any google searches so far.

Building with Swift for iOS8+

Comment: This is a very broad question, and you should narrow it down to get some help. For example, do you already have a list of valid words and want a data structure and algorithm that can be used to find possible matches on the grid fast?

Comment: That is correct. I'm using the wordlist from Letterpress that is available on GitHub.

Comment: Think about using a Trie, I've made a similar game and this was the only way I could get decent performance with a large dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jamesp mentioned, a trie is your best bet. You have a couple of advantages for yourself here, the first one being is that you can bail out the second you have found a word. You don't have to scan the whole grid for all possible words, just find one and be done with it. Start with any random letter and look at the ones around it, and match those up against the trie. If you find a match, continue with the letters around that one and so on until you have found a word or a dead end. If the current start tile doesn't have a full word around it, go on to the next tile in the grid and try from there again.

Comment: @JeremyP [This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/488611/james-p) guy. He wrote a comment on the question.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that, I was editing my answer to add a trie to it at the time he was posting.

Comment: I was thinking of something along those lines but was not aware of the trie concept. Thanks I'll read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not construct your grid by first putting a randomly selected valid word somewhere on it and then filling in the blank spaces with random letters.

**Edit**

So if you can't do that, one way that might be quick enough is to organise your words in a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This might be enough to make the search fast enough. The idea would be to iterate through the letters in the grid and for each one select the appropriate first letter in the trie. This makes the search for each allowed neighbour smaller and so on until either your trie runs out or you find a word.

I would also select the random letters in a distribution that mirrors the distribution of letters in your dictionary. One way to do this is to

- count the number of each letter in your dictionary to give each one a weight
- generate a random number between 0 and the total of all the weights
- iterate through the letters, subtracting each one's weight from your random number
- when the subtraction gets below zero, the letter you are on is the one you want.

You can speed the above up by using a binary search but there's only 26 letters, so the extra complication isn't worth it.

Comment: He can't do that because as the player finds words, the letters from those words are replaced with random tiles.  It's probably something like "Bejeweled", where the tiles "fall" from above to replace removed spaces or something.  With that method, he could ensure the initial puzzle state has words, but after the first match, there would be no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to take quite a bit of processing time to get through a problem like that, especially since the words can twist and turn.

There's a couple of ways to approach that, but if you have a fast dictionary lookup, you'll probably want to step through your puzzle, starting at the upper-left tile, and look at the letter there.  Say it is "S".  Your dictionary will provide you with a list of acceptable "S" words.  You can step through those words looking at the second letter of each word and seeing if there is an adjacent tile to the current tile that has that letter.  If not, you're done - move to the next tile.  If so, you can do that exact same process again recursively for words starting with "S" and the next letter.

For instance, say the current tile is "S".  You'd look up your list of "S" words, and start looping through them.  One of them is "Syzygy".  If there is no adjacent "Y" tile, you're done - move to the next word.  If there is a "Y" tile adjacent, look around that tile for a "Z".  If there is none, you're done.  Otherwise, move to the second "Y", and so on.  (If tiles can only be used once for a word, you may have to remember tiles to exclude from later letters, so that the player can't use the same "Y" three times to spell that "Syzygy".)

I'd wager that the vast majority of your tiles would be excluded quickly with this approach, but it still could take a long time to process, especially if your grid is large.  You can address this by running that check in the background, and letting the player continue to play while it's checking, and then show an alert when you finally ascertain that there are no valid plays.

Keep in mind that just because there is one valid word in the puzzle, it doesn't mean that it's still really solvable by the end user.  This sort of puzzle isn't like your typical match-three games where if you just look long enough, you'll find the match.  Most "valid word" lists are going to contain many words that most people aren't going to know.  Words like "propale" and "helctic" and "syzygy".  (And you can't exclude words like that, because then when someone finds one, instead of the intense satisfaction of finding an obscure word, they get the intense frustration of "But that's a real word, dang it!")

So, probably what you want is an assessment of how obscure the existing words are.  If "dog" is the only word available, that's still probably pretty solvable for most people, whereas if the only words available are "propale" and "helctic" and "syzygy", that's probably impossible for most people, even though there are more words available.

To do that, you'll need to rank your dictionary words as to how common they are, and then add up the ubiquity score for the existing words to make that sort of assessment, and calling the puzzle "unsolvable" if it doesn't reach a certain threshold for that score.  Same algorithm, but you'll be adding a score for each word you find.  And you can't just quit when you find the first word, but you can quit when you reach that threshold.

If this sounds daunting, then that's because you've designed yourself into a corner.  A better approach might be letting the user swap some tiles if they're stumped, or letting them add a wildcard letter, etc.  Things that *they* manage, so that even if there are no real words in the puzzle, they still have strategic options.  Then you don't even have to solve this problem, and it solves the deeper problem of knowing whether a puzzle is *practically* solvable rather than *technically* solvable.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this. Your concerns are similar to mine but if I was thinking of a bullseye approach. Say I have a letter 'S' as the first letter then the next letter away as a group of possible second letters and so on to 7. Then using a regular expressions or predicted I could query the DB for all potentials at once.  It's not a complete thought yet but something I was trying to wrap my head around. I like your idea of a word threshold. That could introduce a difficulty factor to the concept. I was also already planning on the mechanics of a swap, shuffle feature regardless.